# How to many2many Odoo domain filter

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have **supply.conditions** and **purchase.request models**. In **purchase.request** I have many2many relation field:

```
supply_ids  = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='supply.conditions', relation='purchase_supply_rel', column1='purchase_requests_id', column2='supply_conditions_id',string='Supply Conditions')
```

In **supply.conditions** model I need to add **domain filter** to check that supply.conditions id is in purchase_supply_rel table. I want to change SQL:

```
select * from supply_conditions a
inner join purchase_supply_rel b
on a.id = b.supply_conditions_id
```

to many2many relation domain.

I tied to make domain filter like that:

```
[('id', '=', purchase_supply_rel.supply_conditions_id)]
```

But I got an error:

```
ValueError: "name 'purchase_supply_rel' is not defined" while evaluating
```

What is wrong? Do I have to have the same many2many relation in my supply.conditions model?

Comment: Can you explain me better what you wish to achieve? What exactly you are filtering and where? (ex: filtering `res.users` in `res.partner` m2m field)

Comment: I want to filter supply_conditions_id's which are in purchase_supply_rel table. But need to set this domain in my supply.conditions model tree view

Answer (score 0):

For filtering Many2many field you can use

```
<field name="m2m_field" domain="[('field', '=', True)]"/>
```

So using domain `[('id', 'in', ids)]` will filter related objects as usual

Comment: I tied [('id', 'in',(supply_conditions_id))] but got error:ValueError: "name 'supply_conditions_ids' is not defined" while evaluating. Maybe it is not possible to do filtering on supply.conditions model...

Comment: `supply_conditions_id` should be current record's attribute

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explan?

Comment: if you want to filter using computed data you should create computed field for this and use it in tree view as invisible field

Comment: The problem in your case is that odoo can't see your field from current scope

Comment: Every time, field which you are using should be visible and accessible from current scope

Comment: So I have to create bidirectional many2many field in supply.conditions model as I understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145850/discussion-between-dachi-darchiashvili-and-fueggit).

Comment: add the field supply_conditions_id in your view , So you wont get the ValueError